# Accessing data stored in complex arrays

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, fortran90

I'm writing some fortran code where I'm having difficulty visualizing how the data in a hierarchy of arrays is stored, which is causing me troubles with how to manipulate a subset of this data.  I've read-in some data stored in an unformatted binary PLOT3D file.  The data format looks like the following:

1. 1 int (nblocks): number of blocks (or zones) in a computational mesh
2. 4 x nblocks ints: (ni(m), nj(m), nk(m), nvars(m)): number of i, j, and k points in each block along with a number of solution variables in each block.
3. loop over blocks (m)
4. ni(m) x nj(m) x nk(m)x nvars(m) floats (q(ni,nj,nk,nv,m)): solution variables at each i, j, and k points for each block.
5. end loop over blocks

```
program my_program

use iso_fortran_env

implicit none

character(*), parameter :: soln_file = 'my_file_name.q'

integer :: nblks, io_stat, imax, jmax, kmax, nv, m

integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: ni, nj, nk, nvars

real(real64), dimension (:,:,:,:), allocatable :: qq
real(real64), dimension (:,:,:,:,:), allocatable :: q

open(unit=10, form='unformatted', file=soln_file, status='old', iostat=io_stat)

if ( io_stat /= 0 ) then
    write(*,*) '*** Error reading solution file ', soln_file, ' ***'
    stop
end if

read(10) nblks

allocate( ni(nblks), nj(nblks), nk(nblks) )

read(10) ( ni(m), nj(m), nk(m), nvars(m), m = 1, nblks )

imax = maxval(ni)
jmax = maxval(nj)
kmax = maxval(nk)
nv = maxval(nvars)

allocate( q(imax,jmax,kmax,nv,nblks) )

do m = 1, nblks
    allocate( qq(ni(m),nj(m),nk(m),nvars(m)) )

    read(10) qq(ni(m),nj(m),nk(m),nvars(m))

    q(1:ni(m),1:nj(m),1:nk(m),1:nvars(m),m) = qq

    deallocate( qq )
end do

close(10)

deallocate( ni, nj, nk, nvars, q )

stop

end program my_program
```

In my case, I'm interested in extracting a subset, or just modifying the values in place, of a single solution variable at all of the points in every block.  It seems like I should end up with the solution values for that variable at each i, j, and k point for every block in a 3 x nblocks array.

However, I get a seg fault at run time which indicates to me that I'm not sizing the array correctly.

Comment: I've updated my original comment with the snippet of relevant code from my program to illustrate how the array is being formed.  The array q holds solution data at each i, j, and k point in a block for multiple blocks.  Further, the solution data exists in any number of variables.  I'm interested in how to extract a subset of the of the solution data for just a single variable.

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. Prepare a real [mcve], test it and make sure it exhibits the right error. There is really nothing special about complex arrays, most likely you have some kind of error that can happen anywhere. To find it you must show the **actual** code.

Comment: Code should compile now.

Comment: Yes, but no-one can test it, because we do not have the required data files. Can't you really make a **minimal** example that does not require external data?

Comment: No, I can't provide the actual solution file, or a working sample of it.  It's a a very large unformatted binary file, and I don't have a visual understanding of how the data within it is structured beyond the simple header which lists the number of blocks, and the i-, j-, and k-extents for each block.  My question is more fundamental in how to extract a subset of a multidimensional array.  In this specific example, I'm looking for an answer as to how to extract all of the solution data for 1 variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your block of code

```
do m = 1, nblks
    allocate( qq(ni(m),nj(m),nk(m),nvars(m)) )

    read(10) qq(ni(m),nj(m),nk(m),nvars(m))

    q(1:ni(m),1:nj(m),1:nk(m),1:nvars(m),m) = qq

    deallocate( qq )
end do
```

You're only reading 4 values pour `qq`, instead of `ni(m) x nj(m) x nk(m) x nvars(m)`.
Then you're trying to copy theses values into `q` wich is not conformant.

It seems to me that the correct loop should be

```
do m = 1, nblks
    allocate( qq(ni(m),nj(m),nk(m),nvars(m)) )

    do iv = 1 ,nvars(m)
      do ik = 1 ,nk(m)
        do ij = 1 ,nj(m)
          do ii = 1 ,ni(m)
             read(10) qq(ii,ij,ik,iv)
          end do
        end do
      end do
    end do

    q(1:ni(m),1:nj(m),1:nk(m),1:nvars(m),m) = qq

    deallocate( qq )
end do
```

I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but there's something *fishy* here.